# Div is dragged instead of horizontal scroll in WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

In a WinForm application (Framework 3.5) with IE11 a simple HTML page with a horizontally scrollable content instead of scrolling drags the page:

[image]

While if i open IE11 standalone it scrolls as have to.

The WebBrowser is created as the following:

```
Private Sub VediTagli()
    Dim webNEWTES As New WebBrowser
    webNEWTES.Name = "webNEWTES"

    webNEWTES.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    'webNEWTES.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = False
    webNEWTES.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False



    'AddHandler webNEWTES.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf webNEWCLI_DocumentCompleted
    AddHandler webNEWTES.Navigating, AddressOf webNEWTES_Navigating
    AddHandler webNEWTES.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf webNEWTES_DocumentCompleted
    webNEWTES.Top = lstDETT.Top
    webNEWTES.Left = lstDETT.Left
    webNEWTES.Height = lstDETT.Height
    webNEWTES.Width = lstDETT.Width




    webNEWTES.Visible = True
    If SONO_IN_MODIFICA_BP = True Then
        webNEWTES.Navigate("http://127.0.0.1/webquery/VisualTicket.aspx?ORARIO=" & Format(DateTime.Now, "HH.mm.ss"))
    Else
        webNEWTES.Navigate("http://127.0.0.1/webquery/VisualTicket.aspx?client=true" & "&ORARIO=" & Format(DateTime.Now, "HH.mm.ss"))
    End If

    'webNEWTES.Url = New Uri("http://127.0.0.1/webquery/VisualTicket.aspx?client=true")
    'webNEWTES.Navigate(IP_CREACLI & "&ORARIO=" & Format(DateTime.Now, "HH.mm.ss"), Nothing, Nothing, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)")

    'webNEWTES.DocumentText = ""
    'webNEWTES.Navigate("about:blank")
    webNEWTES.BringToFront()
    Panel2.Controls.Add(webNEWTES)
End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't mention whether the WebBrowser Control in your application uses IE11 (Edge) emulation mode. If you haven't set it explicitly, you're on IE7 compatibility mode.

Comment: @Jimi it is on IE11 set on sys register, the issue was solved by disabling `FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by disabling **Legacy Input Model** in sys register.

As per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330732(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#legacy-input-model) it was needed to disable `FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE` as following:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
   SOFTWARE
      Microsoft
         Internet Explorer
            Main
               FeatureControl
                  FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE
                     contoso.exe = (DWORD) 00000000
```